# ibm rhapsody compilation

Tags: java, rhapsody

i couldn't compile using ibm rhapsody; i have this error:

Building ------------  MainDefaultComponent.class   ------------

```
   Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.0\Share\etc\jdkmake.bat" DefaultComponent.bat build

   Unable to compile

   Build Done
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

[Unable to run Rational Rhapsody due to "Unable to compile" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103958/unable-to-run-rational-rhapsody-due-to-unable-to-compile-error/5665183#5665183)

Answer (score 0):

hmm did you select proper JDK during installation of Rhapsody? it doesn't seem so.
Although some of tweaks mentioned above might work, I strongly suggest reinstalling your Rhapsody, because this tool makes many adjustments on internal scripts, based on the location of JDK you provide. good luck.